# c#: " if " is working weird

Tags: c#, if-statement

i was developing my own BASIC language. When i was making IF command i got this:

```
object firstElement = tokens[1];
object secondElement = tokens[3];
string conditionType = tokens[2];
bool resultOfCondition = false;

if (conditionType == "==") 
{
    if (firstElement == secondElement) 
    {
        resultOfCondition = true; 
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG: true!");
    } 
    else 
    {
        resultOfCondition = false;
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG: false!");
    }
} 
else if (conditionType == "!=") 
{
} 
else 
{
    throw new System.ArgumentException("It's not any type of contidion!", "original");
}
```

where

```
tokens[1] = 3;
tokens[3] = 3;
tokens[2] = "==";
```

and my console's output is really weird:

```
DEBUG: false!
```

I don't know what is going on, and why output is false!
Can someone help me?

Comment: what happens when you step through the program?

Comment: What is the value of firstElement and secondElement? It's displaying exactly what you've told it to.

Comment: You should be using `firstElement.Equals( secondElement )`.  The problem is `==` performs reference equality for `object`.  The objects may both contain the same boxed value of `3`, but they're not the same objects, they're two different objects with the same content.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight tokens[0] is "IF". I use it to check what command is it.

Comment: @Kyle It woked! Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are boxing the integer values and each (box) is a separate instance, thus the comparison will fail.

change

```
 object firstElement = 3;
 object secondElement = 3;
```

to

```
 int firstElement = 3;
 int secondElement = 3;
```

or change your comparer to `firstElement.Equals(secondElement)`

Answer (score 4):

Look here

```
object firstElement = tokens[1];
object secondElement = tokens[3];
```

While you know that `firstElement` and `secondElement` are both actually `Int32s` with the value of **3**, the runtime environment sees them as objects.  That's because you placed the values into an array of objects (am assuming) and then assign them to object variables.

Your struct values are now boxed, each one in a different object.  And when you compare different objects using `==`, it defaults to reference equivalence.  Since your value is boxed in two different objects, the result is false.

For more information on how boxing works, read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

Comment: @MeirionHughes well, the question is a bit on the easy side.  I gave a kind of sarcastic comment about debugging, but honestly OP very well might have, and is baffled by the result he's seeing, because the debug process wouldn't scream "THIS IS BOXED".  Deleted and answered instead.  But it's definitely borderline, and it's reasonable (also in my opinion) to downvote answers on questions that don't show effort.